# Error: "This field name is not known" while opening Crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, runtime-error

Working on a Migration (VB6 to VB.Net(VS 2005)) application, where some of the reports are loaded in the application. The VB application is using the Crystal reports version 8. While migrating the application, we used the Crystal decisions and tried to load the report. Few of the reports are working fine, few are giving error (like boolean is required here, This field name is not known etc..). For few of the issues we have regenerated the report in CR XI it worked fine and few are giving the performance issue, but few reports are giving the same error as "This field name is not known".

To load the report we followed the steps.

1. Based on the user access level, the report connects to different DSNs.
2. Applies the LogonInfo to the report.
3. Sets the datatable as the datasource to the report
4. View the report.

If we run the application to load the report, it's throwing this error:

> This field Name is not known.
>   Error in file C:\Docs~\User\Local~\Temp\SampleReport{EE6CC25A-D216-496C-AA95-E2F0C61718C6}.rpt:
>   Error in Formula .
>   '{ViewReport.field} ="AB'"
>   This field Name is not known".

I have tried changing the setdatabaselocation in database expert. Still getting the error.

The reports giving the error are using a **View** in their queries. Is this causing the issue?

Comment: ASAP? Takes much more time, sorry. Maybe SAP will help with ASAP queries?

Comment: @Arvo: Pretty sure that by "ASAP", they meant "As Soon As Possible". I've complained about overuse of abbrevs in questions before...

Comment: What happens if you select Database | Verify Database?

Comment: @Cody Gray: of course ASAP means "as soon as possible". I meant that all questions, marked as "I need help ASAP" or "urgent" will cause much less friendly responses and slow answers. Urgent requests are best solved by using paid support channels, thereby I pointed to SAP as Crystal Reports current owner and (paid) support source. Similarity between abbreviations SAP and ASAP is purely coincidential.

Answer (score 0):

Check your formula fields in the report. Often times this error is not a result of a dataset issue as much as a custom field, or formula withing a group or a section.

Comment: The Formula is in the Where condition of the selection query.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the condition inside bracket like this...

```
({ViewReport.field} ="AB'")
```